# if statement results in 'command not found error`

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have this code:

```
ColumnInformation=`sqlite3 $database "PRAGMA table_info($table);"`
```

and it works perfect, but I need add the `if` statement:

```
if [$table != "Order"]; then
    ColumnInformation=`sqlite3 $database "PRAGMA table_info($table);"`
else
    ColumnInformation=`sqlite3 $database "PRAGMA table_info('Order');"`
fi
```

it throws `command not found` error. Could you tell me why ?

best, Tomek

Comment: You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be lack of space either side of `[` and `]` and you need to use "backticks" to get the output from a sub-command:

```
if [ $table != "Order" ]; then
    ColumnInformation=`sqlite3 $database "PRAGMA table_info('$table');"`
else
    ColumnInformation=`sqlite3 $database "PRAGMA table_info('Order');"`
fi
```

However the test appears to be pointless anyway as `$table` is "Order" in the second case anyway.  Also note that you were missing single-quotes around `$table` in the first case.